# Grails with Java,Spring MVC and no database resource

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-mvc

I have a web project running on a machine with no direct access to a database. My goal is to build it using the template offered by Grails (when scaffolding is enabled) but I prefer my code to be in java without using any database resource. I have looked for a couple of hours in search engines to find an example or tutorial that will use Grails + Spring MVC +JAVA with not database resource and at the same time would take advantage of the scaffolding template of grails so that the amount of HTML code that must be written by me is effectively zero. Any ideas suggestions or resources on how to handle this appropriately are appreciated.

Comment: well i guess you can use files to store your data , but without storing the data anywhere it really is not meaningful to create such application

Comment: I will use a database but not directly.

Comment: where exactly do you not want datasource to exist ??

Comment: It does not really matter for the question, it could be accessed for example from a JAVA API that will be coded in the controller classes.

Comment: A better place for calling apis is services.

Comment: And how about the springmvc plugin? http://grails.org/plugin/springmvc

Comment: I'd suggest to read http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html, as Grails is referred as 'Spring MVC application in disguise' ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can help, but a guide we just published came to mind. It might not be helpful...it's based on your need.
Just curiously, why not use a database?  It seems cloud options would make database availability a non-issue.

In any event, isn't there some open source piece that makes a `JDBC` connect to `CSVs`? I remember, we could connect our app to `CSV` with one of the analytic packages I used to use.